# Fallout 4 - selection in settlement

Tags: fallout-4

I was just wondering if there is a way to customize selections in settlements by using console, mod or something.

By selection I mean when in build mode I hold "E" key while aiming at object, it will select everything what belongs to the stack (House with stuff, connected walls etc.)

And I would like to know how:
1. Remove selection stack
2. Clone selection stack

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What do you mean by "remove selection stack" and "clone selection stack"?

Comment: Finally an answer. I mean when you are inside settlement build mode, you can hold "E" (PC) instead of pressing to select "stack/bulk/multiple objects at one". Stack means that it will select everything what is close or snapped into the objects. For example whole player-built house with objects inside etc.
By remove I mean to remove this item from settlement, basically scrap/destroy.

Comment: Okay, so (1) is scrap a whole stack at once? What about (2)? You're looking to create a duplicate stack? Like craft the whole thing at once?

Comment: Yes scrap or just delete ( disable command ), Clone : so for example when I build a house, then I can copy it and move it elsewhere with all of its content.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do either built-in. Possibly with a mod, since basically anything is possible with a mod. Keep in mind that there's no guarantee that everything in the stack is even scrappable or craftable.

Comment: It looks like there's a mod called Cell Ripper on nexus mods that may help. I can't look at the details right now, for some reason.

Comment: Yes you're right, but once I built these items there should be a way to scrap them... otherwise 'disable' command could do the trick when it comes to deleting.
Thanks anyway I though that there is a way I missing.
Edit: The file is hidden for me as well.